# count how many day fall into specific date a range of year

Tags: php, date

Initially I am trying to create a function to display how many times does a specific day fall into particular date. for example how many times does Saturday fall into January 1st of certain year to certain year.

```
<?php 

$firstDate = '01/01/2000';
$endDate = '01/01/2012';
$newYearDate= '01/01';

# convert above string to time
$time1 = strtotime($firstDate);
$time2 = strtotime($endDate);
$newYearTime = strtotime($newYearDate);

for($i=$time1; $i<=$time2; $i++){
    $saturday = 0;
    $chk = date('D', $newYearTime); #date conversion
   if($chk == 'Sat' && $chk == $newYearTime){ 
      $saturday++;    
      } 
}
echo $saturday;

?>
```

Comment: but it takes forever to loop

Comment: the way I would do it is 1. find the first week day you want starting from $firstDate 2. find the total number of days from the week day (not $firstDate) to $endDate 3. $total_number_of_days % 7 and that should be it.

Comment: @kennypu That doesn't seem right. If you add one day to the end day, your procedure will add 1 to the result, but the result usually shouldn't change.

Comment: @Barmar good point, I just thought that up real quick, didn't really think about it. I suppose dividing by 7, and losing the remainders will be the correct way.

Comment: Your loop is taking forever because you're incrementing one second at a time. Try doing it one day at a time with `$i+=86400` instead.

Comment: @kennypu I think you don't understand the question. He doesn't want to know the number of Saturdays between two dates. He wants to know the number of years where January 1 falls on a Saturday.

Comment: my question is for example from  1990 to 2012 , how many Saturdays falls into 1st of January i want to create a counter and display the total time that Saturday fall into 1st of January.

Comment: @GeorgeLim I think you're confusing people with your backward phrasing. We say "_date_ falls __on__ _day-of-week_", not "_day-of-week_ falls __into__ _date_".

Answer (score 1):

You can only have a saturday to be in, say January 1, once in a year, so:

```
$firstDate = '01/01/2000';
$endDate = '01/01/2012';

$time1 = strtotime($firstDate);
$time2 = strtotime($endDate);

$saturday = 0;
while ($time1 < $time2) {

    $time1 = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", $time1) . " +1 year");
    $chk = date('D', $time1);
    if ($chk == 'Sat') {
        $saturday++;
    }

}

echo "Saturdays at 01/01/yyyy: " . $saturday . "\n";
```

The line I changed was:

```
$time1 = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($time1)) . " +1 year");
```

to

```
$time1 = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", $time1) . " +1 year");
```

as `$time1` is already in seconds from the epoch -- the format required for date.

Comment: hi Rubens, why is ur code takes forever to run? how can i make it faster?

Comment: @GeorgeLim sorry, I did not test it; I will try it here and edit with the adjustments; just a second!

Answer (score 0):

[`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) gives you *seconds* since 1970-01-01. Since you're interested in days only, you can increment your loop by 86400 seconds per day to speed up your calculation

```
for($i = $time1; $i <= $time2; $i += 86400) {
...
}
```

There are several points

- move `$saturday` out of your loop
- check new year's eve with day of year
- check the loop counter `$i` instead of `$newYearTime`

This should work

```
$firstDate = '01/01/2000';
$endDate = '01/01/2012';

# convert above string to time
$time1 = strtotime($firstDate);
$time2 = strtotime($endDate);

$saturday = 0;
for($i=$time1; $i<=$time2; $i += 86400){
    $weekday = date('D', $i);
    $dayofyear = date('z', $i);
    if($weekday == 'Sat' && $dayofyear == 0){ 
        $saturday++;    
    } 
}

echo "$saturday\n";
```

Comment: Thanks. but why is my counter still giving me zero, i have given the condition if it matches SAT and it is on 1st of January it should add one to the counter

Comment: Thanks for that Olaf, but there is a problem, if i change the date to 1900, the counter become lesser, why is that happen? it should give me more counter

Comment: @GeorgeLim When I start from `2000-01-01`, I get `3`. From `1900-01-01`, it gives `16`.

Comment: does it matter if i use different date format. my computer is giving me less counter.when i choose below 1900

Comment: @GeorgeLim On my system (Ubuntu 12.04), the date format doesn't matter. I get the same result with either `1850-01-01` or `01/01/1850`. Maybe this has to do with 64 bit vs 32 bit.